# Angular 2 Child Routes not Navigating

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have a route configuration, simplified and reproduced below. My issue is that whenever I try to navigate to `/teams/something/settings/users/invite`, I get instantly redirected to `/teams/something/settings/users/list`. I'd love some help figuring out what is wrong with my navigation.

The guards all work as expected.

```
const settingsRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: 'teams/:id/settings',
    component: BaseComponent,
    children: [{
        component: TeamSettingsComponent,
        path: '',
        children: [{
            path: 'users',
            children: [{
                path: 'invite',
                component: InviteUsersComponent,
                canDeactivate: [InviteUsersUnsavedChangesGuard]
            }, {
                path: 'list',
                component: UsersComponent,
                canDeactivate: [UsersUnsavedChangesGuard]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                pathMatch: 'full',
                redirectTo: 'list'
            }]
        }]
    }],
}];
```

Comment: By trying to navigate, you mean that you put /teams/something/settings/users/invite manually in the browser right?

Comment: you don't have ```/users``` in any of your paths

Comment: @Jota.Toledo either by navigating with routerLink or by manual entry.

Comment: @LLL I do, it is nested in teams/:id/settings/users

Comment: oh, sorry, my bad

Comment: Could you create a plnkr?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo this should do it http://plnkr.co/edit/f6t9WMxoIbT4tgnZ1Uya updated link